# Python web3: How to get multiple addresses from a Private key?

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, web3py, go-ethereum

Is it possible for me to get **multiple public address** using **python web3**?

I want to create a unique public address for each of my customers from my private key in python web3.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create multiple addresses from a private key, because each private key corresponds one public key.

[You can create multiple private keys from a seed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68914094/315168).

Comment: But How can I generate new accounts from a node? I guess we can generate a new account from a passphrase.

Comment: yes, you need to generate new accounts from the passphrase